# fsharp quotation Expr list -> Expr handling

Tags: f#, quotations

What can I do to get the following working?

I need to make a function that accepts a Expr list and returns a Expr (Expr list -> Epxr).

```
type DataObject() =
    let data = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, obj>()
    member this.AddValue propertyIndex value = data.Add(propertyIndex, value)
    member this.GetValue propertyIndex = 
        match data.TryGetValue propertyIndex with
        | (true, value) -> value
        | (false, _)    -> box "property not found"

...
(fun args -> 
    <@@ 
        let data = new DataObject(values)
        args |> List.iteri (fun i arg -> data.AddValue i <@@ (%%arg) : string @@>)
        data 
    @@>)
```

I made the DataObject type to add the values of the args in. But somehow I cannot manage to get the code iterating through the different args (args.[0] .. args.[i]). The message I get is:

> The variable 'arg' is bound in a quotation but is used as part of a spliced expression. This is not permitted since it may escape its scope.

If I access the args explicitly (args.[0], args.[1], ...) the solution works, but as soon as I try to add the iteration I run into problems. Because the list of args is flexible in length, this is not a feasible solution for me.

I've tried different approaches, but unsuccesful. Is there some solution?

[Edit]

Adding the feedback of Tomas in my solution brings me this:

```
type DataObject(values: obj []) =
    let propertyMap = new Map<int, obj>(values |> Seq.mapi (fun i value -> (i, value)))
    member this.GetValue propertyIndex : obj = 
        match propertyMap.TryFind propertyIndex with
        | Some(value) -> value
        | None        -> box "property not found"

(fun args ->  
    let boxedArgs = 
        args |> List.map (fun arg -> 
            match arg with
            | Quotations.Patterns.Var var -> 
                if var.Type = typeof<int> then 
                    <@@ (box (%%arg: int)) @@>
                else if var.Type = typeof<string> then 
                    <@@ (box (%%arg: string)) @@>
                else if var.Type = typeof<System.Guid> then 
                    <@@ (box (%%arg: System.Guid)) @@>
                else 
                    failwith ("Aha: " + var.Type.ToString())
            | _ -> failwith ("Unknown Expr as parameter"))
        <@@ new DataObject(%%(Expr.NewArray(typeof<obj>, boxedArgs))) @@>))
```

And this works! Only thing is that I want to get rid of the if ... else construction to get the right conversion. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the edit, I think you could replace the `if` with `Expr.Coerce(arg, typeof<obj>)` - That should give you an expression that represents the boxing of any other expression `arg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tricky question! To understand why your code does not work, you need to clearly distinguish between two levels - at one level (*meta*), you are composing quotations and at the other level (*base*) you are running some code using data object.

The reason why your code does not work is that `args` is a list of expressions at the meta-level and you are trying to iterate over it at the base-level. The iteration needs to happen at the meta-level.

One way to solve this is to do the iteration at the meta-level and generate a list of functions that call `AddValue` for all arguments. Then you can compose the functions:

```
(fun args -> 
    // Given arguments [a0; a1; ...] Generate a list of functions:
    //
    //   [ fun data -> data.AddValue 0 a0; data ]
    //   [ fun data -> data.AddValue 1 a1; data ... ]
    args 
    |> List.mapi (fun i arg -> 
      <@ fun (data:DataObject) -> data.AddValue i (%%arg : string); data @>)

    // Compose all the functions just by calling them - note that the above functions 
    // take DataObject, mutate it and then return it. Given [f0; f1; ...] produce:
    //
    //    ... (f1 (f0 (new DataObject())))
    //
    |> List.fold (fun dobj fe -> <@ (%fe) (%dobj) @>) <@ new DataObject() @> )
```

This is fun to write, but it gets really complicated. In practice, you could make things a lot easier by adding `AddValues` method to your data object (taking `obj[]`) and using `Expr.NewArray` to create a single array (at the base-level) containing the values of all the parameters (from the meta-level):

```
<@@ let d = new DataObject()
    d.AddValues(%(Expr.NewArray(typeof<obj>, args)))
    d @@>
```

Comment: Hi Tomas. Thanks for the input, it got me a few steps further. I've edited the question with the solution so far. Do you also have some ideas for the if..then constrution? (see edit in question)